# What is the point of OptionalInt?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-stream, option-type

I understand its there to circumvent the double wrapping performance issue of `Optional<Integer>` however in this example:

```
OptionalInt x = IntStream.range(1, 1000000)
        .map(y -> y * 2)
        .filter(y -> y > 10)
        .findAny();
```

The intermediaries are the ones dealing with lots of values i.e. `IntStream`, `IntUnaryOperator` etc. The `OptionalInt` is only created once at the end.

Is it really worth having `OptionalInt` just for that single return object at the end?

Comment: There are many other uses for `OptionalInt` than this one. And since it existed anyway, they might just as well use it here too.

Comment: I am unable to think of a use other than a streaming context and even there it looks like it has limited use. Do you have a link to some other uses?

Comment: I could return it from a method but the caller would lack some useful methods. So I would return Optional<Integer>. I could understand if it was a million of them in a streaming context but even there only one is created.

Comment: For me personally, I think OptionalInt is a much cleaner way to tell a possible unpresent Return value than primitive magic numbers like `-1` or boxed `null`.

Comment: @codeflush.dev null is never boxed. The optional (either flavour) can be empty.

Comment: I meant boxed type (Integer) to be able to Return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, remember that there might be *no* value present after the `filter` method usage (or any that returns a different number of objects like `reduce`). It is not guaranteed that a value would be *always* present. That's behind the design of returning something that says that the value *might* be there instead of `null` that likely causes errors.

> Is it really worth having OptionalInt just for that single return object at the end?

Yes, it is worth it. `OptionalInt` is a representation of `Optional<Integer>` that returns a primitive `int` instead (of course the value must be present). We can say it wraps `int`. Since boxing is related only to primitives, I guess introducing such object/s is for sake of convenience and boxing operation overhead avoidance.

```
OptionalInt optionalInt = IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .filter(i -> i > 5)
        .map(i -> i + 1)
        .findAny();
int resultInt1 = optionalInt.getAsInt();  // PROS: explicit method name advantage
```

```
Optional<Integer> optional =  IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .filter(i -> i > 5)
        .mapToObj(i -> i + 1)             // CONS: boxing (int -> Integer)
        .findAny();
int resultInt2 = optional.get();          // CONS: boxing (Integer -> int)
                                          // CONS: not explicit method name
```

Comment: If there is no value after the filter then that is handled with an empty IntStream. My question was around the fact that I can only see one OptionalInt being created so all that is saved is one box 'Integer'

Comment: As I said, the first thing is boxing operation avoidance, the second thing is the convenience of returning a primitive type and explicit method naming.

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to return if it doesn't find any?

```
int x = IntStream.range(1, 1000000)
        .map(y -> y * 2)
        .filter(y -> y > 10)
        .findAny().orElse(-23);
```

Comment: Optional<Integer> ?

Comment: But then you have to box the result.  Here it either returns a positive integer or -23 as I am not returning an OptionalInt but the value or a default.

Comment: So the performance improvement is the two boxes you would remove here: .findAny().orElse(-23); ? Again it seems a small improvement. If it were for the million records I could understand.

Comment: Well, why map to an Integer if you don't have too?

Comment: @AndyCribbens but it may be used for the Million records. OptionalInt is defined ins the spec, so its for every possible type of application